# Включение анимации добавления пунка в RecyclerView, после закрытия DialogFragment

Tags: android

У меня есть `RecyclerView` и `DialogFragment`. `RecyclerView` заполняется данными из `List` (переменная `mList`), а `DialogFragment` добавляет новые. После ввода данных в фрагменте, я упорядочиваю их и передаю в активность, которая добавляет их в `mList` и `RecyclerView`. Проблема в том, что активность обновляет данные в то время, как клавиатура еще открыта и нет красивой анимации добавления нового пункта списка, как при удалении. Как сделать так, чтобы сначала исчезала клавиатура, а только потом добавлялся новый пункт?

---

Вот часть кода фрагмента и активности (остальное части кода не имеют отношения к данной проблеме):

`mList` — `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`, которым заполняется адаптер.

`mAdapter` — ссылка на адаптер.

```
    //Метод в фрагменте
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ArrayList<String> record = new ArrayList<>();

        record.add(mEditText_1.getText().toString());
        record.add(mEditText_2.getText().toString());
        record.add(mEditText_3.getText().toString());

        ((MyActivity) getActivity()).updateRecord(record);
        dismiss();

    }

    //Метод в активности
    public void addRecord(ArrayList<String> newRecord) {
        mList.add(newRecord);
        mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mList.size() - 1);
    }
```

---

Я уже пробовал вызывать метод после `dismiss()`, вызывать `this.wait()` в фрагменте и самом методе,до добавления пункта, но клавиатура "спала" вместе с фрагментом\активностью и все равно закрывала анимацию!

Answer (score 4):

Перед анимацией программно закройте клавиатуру.

```
void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)  activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```